# How to think about generating all words and retreving the best word given letters for an input

Tags: python, algorithm, priority-queue, trie

I decided to write a little application in python to help me learn to type using the dvorak keyboard layout. In my algorithms class, we discussed trees, and tries, and implemented an autocomplete function.

I grabbed a  word list from [this site](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?revision=61569&view=co). Then I loaded all the words in it into a trie, (which surprisingly only took about a third of a second) and now I am trying to figure out how to make words that are relevant.

I currently am maintaining a priority queue to keep track of which letters the user is typing wrongly the most, and so I remove say 3 letters from this queue to start. If I wanted all the words that started with each of these letters, I could do this, and then probably just filter out all words that don't have any of the other letters that the user types wrongly the most.

is it possible to efficiently (or maybe even not efficiently) get a list of all words with the letters from the priority queue in them, and then filter out so that I get the word that will be the biggest challenge to the typer?

I was able to do this with characters, but the words present an interesting challenge, because the nature of the trie only gets words that have prefixes that start with the letters we have in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a trie here at all? I think you either don't need any advanced structure, or you need something else.

How much words do you want to process? If it takes only a third of a second to load them to a trie, then it will take not much longer to just go through all of them and chose whatever you want. You will have to do this every time, but if it's just 1/3 of a second, it will not be a problem.

Comment: How would I go through each? Just a linear search? Wouldn't that take quite a while to see if each letter is in the word at all?

Comment: @DerekRiemer, A simplest approach will be one linear pass for each word, you can count the total number of occurrences of each letter in just one pass. This will take one pass of each word, which is the same time you use to add it to a trie. A faster approach is to precalculate for each work which letters it contains.

Comment: That gave me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-calculate the TRIE to hold all the sub strings (on top of the real words themselves) as well, where the end of the sub string points to the real word in the TRIE.

This way you can use the code you already have and apply it to sub strings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The solution I came up with combined @shapiro-yaacov's answer with code I wrote.
I scrapped the trie, and used a thing with bins for each letter. Each word is put into a bin for each letter, and then the algorithm adds up letters to find which words have the most wanted letters. I also take a 10th of a point away from words for each letter that I don't want, to encourage my program to give reasonable words, because if I simply were to add up all words with the most letters, I would get huge words.

Here is my Words.py:

```
import string
import random
import operator
class Bin:
    """ 
    A bin is a container that stores words given in a dictionary file.
    It is designed to retrieve all words in this file with the given letters.
    The words are stored in this container in an array and when new words get added,
    the container automatically adds the word to the words list,
    and places them into as many bins as need be.
    For example,
    >>> bin=Bin("words.txt") #get all words from bin.txt
    >>>bin.addWord("about") 
    now, the bins for a, b, o, u, t  will have a pointer to "about".
    Now immagine the bin has the words "king", "fish", and "dish" in it.
    >>> d=bin.getWordWithLetters("sh")
    >>> print d
    ["fish", "dish"]
    """

    def __init__(self, wordsFile):
        """initialize the container from the given file,
        if None, just initialize an empty container.
        """
        self.bins={}
        for i in string.ascii_lowercase+".'&": #these are the letters I need.
            self.bins[i]=[] #initialize an empty list for each bin. 
        if wordsFile == None:
            return
        with open(wordsFile) as words:
            for i in words:
                self.addWord(i.strip("\n"))

    def addWord(self, word):
        for i in word:
            self.bins[i].append(word) #add the word to the bin for each letter in that word.

    def getWordsWithLetters(self, lrs):
        """Gets best word that has the letters lrs in it.         
        For example, if abcdef is given, and the words [has, babe, shame] are there,
        [babe] would be returned because it is the word with the maximum return,
        since it contains b,a,e."""
        words=[]
        for i in lrs:
            words+=self.bins[i]
        #Now we go through the words, and calculate the score of each word.
        #a score is calculated by adding up the number of times a letter from lrs appears in each word.
        # Then we will subtract out the number of 
        for index, item in enumerate(words):
            score=random.randint(0,10) #give some randomness for the typing thing.
            #print(score)
            #score = 0 #to make it deterministic.           
            base=score
            itCounts={}
            for i in lrs:
                itCounts[i]=False
            for letter in item:
                if letter in lrs and (not itCounts[letter]):
                    score+=1
                    itCounts[letter]= True
                else:
                    score-=.1
            words[index] = (item, score)
        words = sorted(words, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        w=[]
        for i in words:
            if i[1] > base:
                w.append(i[0])
        return w[:50]
```